# What does rcu_read_lock() actually do (Linux Kernel)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, locking, rcu

I'm trying to understand rcu_read_lock() synchronization mechanism. From what I understand, rcu_read_lock() is used, where there are several read threads and one write thread, that read/writes the same data, and reading is performed under rcu_read_lock(), and the data are copied for each thread. I wrote a simple driver to test this (read() and write() functions are core):

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
#include <linux/rcupdate.h>
#include <linux/preempt.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>

#define MY_MAJOR 42
#define MY_MAX_MINORS 5

char buf[] = "0";

struct dev_data
{
    struct cdev cdev;
};

struct dev_data devs[MY_MAX_MINORS];

static ssize_t read(struct file *file, char __user *buffer, size_t size, loff_t *offset)
{
    rcu_read_lock();
    while (1)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s", buf);
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();

    return 0;
}

static ssize_t write(struct file *file, const char __user *buffer, size_t size, loff_t *offset)
{
    buf[0] = '1';

    return size;
}

const struct file_operations fops = {
    .read = &read,
    .write = &write,
};

static int __init foo_start(void)
{
    int i, err_code;

    err_code = register_chrdev_region(MKDEV(MY_MAJOR, 0), MY_MAX_MINORS, "Test char driver");
    if (err_code != 0)
        return err_code;

    for(i=0; i<MY_MAX_MINORS; ++i)
    {
        cdev_init(&devs[i].cdev, &fops);
        cdev_add(&devs[i].cdev, MKDEV(MY_MAJOR, i), 1);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit foo_end(void)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<MY_MAX_MINORS; ++i)
    {
        cdev_del(&devs[i].cdev);
    }

    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(MY_MAJOR, 0), MY_MAX_MINORS);
}

module_init(foo_start);
module_exit(foo_end);
```

but when I call the write function during reading, the data is changing under rcu_read_lock() too. Where is my mistake?
P.S. The driver itself is crippy, but my goal was just to test rcu_read_lock().

Comment: As I understand it, it is a mechanism to allow readers to _read_ a potentially stale, _copy_ of some data structure while a writer is _updating_ the master copy.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Actually, in RCU all parts are for the **writer**: It *reads* an object, *copies* it, and *updates* that copy. After that, a pointer to the copy is published for the readers, while the previous object is still alive.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, sorry I didn't make it clear that the writer does all the work. I didn't mean to imply that the reader makes the copy, but I can see how what I wrote is possibly misleading.

Comment: You're not using the [RCU API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt) correctly.

Answer (score 7):

You can find [the RCU documentation on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt) which describe it.

Its introduction is really interesting:

> Although RCU is actually quite simple once you understand it,
> getting there can sometimes be a challenge.  Part of the problem is that
> most of the past descriptions of RCU have been written with the mistaken
> assumption that there is "one true way" to describe RCU.  Instead,
> the experience has been that different people must take different paths
> to arrive at an understanding of RCU.

As you can see, anyone who wants to really understand it must take the time to read the documentation.

To get a basic idea of it:

> The basic idea behind RCU is to split updates into "removal" and
> "reclamation" phases. The removal phase removes references to data
> items within a data structure (possibly by replacing them with
> references to new versions of these data items), and can run
> concurrently with readers.

Read more from the documentation.

Coming now to your question, here is the description of the `rcu_read_lock()` and `rcu_read_unlock()` API functions:

> rcu_read_lock()
>
> void rcu_read_lock(void);
>
> Used by a reader to inform the reclaimer that the reader is entering
> an RCU read-side critical section. It is illegal to block while in
> an RCU read-side critical section, though kernels built with
> CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU can preempt RCU read-side critical sections. Any
> RCU-protected data structure  accessed during an RCU read-side
> critical section is guaranteed to remain unreclaimed for the full
> duration of that critical section. Reference counts may be used in
> conjunction with RCU to maintain longer-term references to data
> structures.
>
> rcu_read_unlock()
>
> void rcu_read_unlock(void);
>
> Used by a reader to inform the reclaimer that the reader is exiting
> an RCU read-side critical section.  Note that RCU read-side critical
> sections may be nested and/or overlapping.

Have a look at the "WHAT ARE SOME EXAMPLE USES OF CORE RCU API?" section in order to have an example of code using them.